# How to combine these two gulp tasks?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

What would be the best way of combing these two tasks? If it's possible.

I think it would get messy and hard to maintain going this approach, so is there a more intelligent way to run these tasks?

Please see the code for my current two gulp tasks bellow. You should be able to see my input files and desired output folder. The reason that I currently have two separate tasks is because there are other folders/files that I don't want compiling (see includePaths).

```
// A task that compiles index SCSS to CSS
gulp.task('sass-index', function () {
    return gulp.src('resources/scss/index.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            precision: 10,
            includePaths: [
                'resources/scss/variables',
                'resources/scss/mixins'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
                '> 1%',
                'last 2 Chrome major versions',
                'last 2 Firefox major versions',
                'last 2 Edge major versions',
                'last 2 Safari major versions',
                'ie 11',
                'last 3 Android major versions',
                'last 3 ChromeAndroid major versions',
                'last 2 iOS major versions'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(uglifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// A task that compiles template SCSS to CSS
gulp.task('sass-templates', function () {
    return gulp.src('resources/scss/templates/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            precision: 10,
            includePaths: [
                'resources/scss/variables',
                'resources/scss/mixins'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
                '> 1%',
                'last 2 Chrome major versions',
                'last 2 Firefox major versions',
                'last 2 Edge major versions',
                'last 2 Safari major versions',
                'ie 11',
                'last 3 Android major versions',
                'last 3 ChromeAndroid major versions',
                'last 2 iOS major versions'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(uglifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/templates'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
const gulpSrc = "resources/scss/",
  gulpDest = "assets/css/",
  filePaths = [
    [
        gulpSrc + "index.scss", 
        gulpDest
    ],
    [
        gulpSrc + "templates/*.scss", 
        gulpDest, gulpDest + "/templates"
    ]
  ]
  ;

gulp.task('sass', function (done) {
    filePaths.map(function (file) {
        return gulp.src(file[0])
            .pipe(sass({
                precision: 10,
                includePaths: [
                    'resources/scss/variables',
                    'resources/scss/mixins'
                ]
            }))
            .pipe(autoprefixer({
                browsers: [
                    '> 1%',
                    'last 2 Chrome major versions',
                    'last 2 Firefox major versions',
                    'last 2 Edge major versions',
                    'last 2 Safari major versions',
                    'ie 11',
                    'last 3 Android major versions',
                    'last 3 ChromeAndroid major versions',
                    'last 2 iOS major versions'
                ]
            }))
            .pipe(uglifycss())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(file[1]))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });
    done();
});
```

Comment: Apart from the error of "The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?" which is easy to fix. I'm choosing this answer. It suits what I was looking for initially.

Comment: No problem, although I think this approach will be harder to maintain over time as filePaths change.    And if you wanted to use the lazypipe in the future as part of another task but not run them all...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [lazypipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe).  With it, you can create a reusable portion of a gulp task.

Untested:

```
var sassTasks = lazypipe()
 .pipe(sass({
            precision: 10,
            includePaths: [
                'resources/scss/variables',
                'resources/scss/mixins'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
                '> 1%',
                'last 2 Chrome major versions',
                'last 2 Firefox major versions',
                'last 2 Edge major versions',
                'last 2 Safari major versions',
                'ie 11',
                'last 3 Android major versions',
                'last 3 ChromeAndroid major versions',
                'last 2 iOS major versions'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(uglifycss());


gulp.task('sass-index', function () {
  return gulp.src('resources/scss/index.scss')
    .pipe(sassTasks())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('sass-templates', function () {
   return gulp.src('resources/scss/templates/*.scss')
     .pipe(sassTasks())
     .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/templates'))
     .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```